# Tracking log-out time

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How do I track log-out time when user unexpectedly closes the browser window and store that time into a database when using ASP.Net/C#?

My problem is that when user does not click "Logout", or the session expired, or directly close the browser, I need to track the log-out.

Comment: You can detect browser close, but it differs between browsers. You can try window.onbeforeunload

Comment: You probably have to be passive-aggressive and "ping" the user to check if the session is alive (signalR or similar comes to mind... have no clue about it, just the idea .. seems like a lot of work for who-knows-how-reliable results)